# Output a command and display only a certain part of information

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, windows-firewall

So I have a query on a Windows 10 system that I'm trying to output firewall rules for. I have temporary firewall rules that get added when a user logs in to the system and would like to add one that removes those rules once a user logs out. The first script looks like this

```
@set enableextensions
@cd /d c:\projects
for /R %%f in (*.exe) do (
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = "Allowed: %%f" dir=out program=%%f action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = "Allowed: %%f" dir=inprogram=%%f action=allow
)
```

How can I script the query to go in reverse to find the name of the rule and remove it?

I've tried parsing the rules by running

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "Rule Name:" | find "Allowed:"
```

The output looks like:

```
Rule Name: Allowed: c:\projects\stuff.exe
```

But I don't know how to parse that information into another string to remove the rule.